# How exactly does the newest version of Kafka store/persist the subscriptions from the consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, subscription, consumer

I've found good reference architecture details for the producer side of Kafka but very little detail on the end to end model for how messages are actually consumed from the topics, how subscriptions are managed, where the subscriptions are persisted (I would assume as a topic on the Group Coordinator?), and when/when the deserialization occurs.

Does anyone have any details to help identify the detailed architecture between the Broker and the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a large section on Consumer model: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theconsumer

Details of the consumer group protocol can be found in these 2 talks:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaeXDh12EhE
- https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-lon19/everything-you-wanted-to-know-kafka-afraid

Topic subscriptions are not persisted on the brokers but instead consumers use a rebalance protocol to share their subscriptions and assign partitions between each other.

Records are sent from the brokers "raw" and consumers are responsible for deserializing the data, hence why `key.deserializer` and `value.deserializer` are mandatory [settings](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs).

Comment: Hello Mickael  ,

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was looking for a more detailed explanation of the architecture behind the consumer process.  I understand the basics on consumers processing and rebalancing.